# Show that for $n\geq 4$ there is a partition $\{1,2,...,n\}=A\cup B$ such that $\{a_i+a_j:i<j\}=\{b_i+b_j:i<j\}$ if and only if $n$ is a power of 2.

Tags: combinatorics

If there is such a partition $A\cup B$ for a given $n$ then $A'=A\cup (n+B)$ and  $B'=B\cup (n+A)$ does the trick for $2n$. Beginning with $A=\{1,4\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$ we get such partitions for any power of 2, which I strongly believe (but can't prove!) are unique. As for the converse, I have no idea on how to proceed. Many thanks in advance for any help on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding the possible partitions by brute force using a script. Here, I list partitions when $n$ is **not** a power of $2$. (For all partitions in this answer, we assume $1 \in A$.)

- One possible partition for $n = 15$:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 15\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 13, 14\}.\\
  \end{align*}
  Verification:
  \begin{array}{rcccl}
  (1 + 4) &=& 5 &=& (2 + 3) \\
  (1 + 6) &=& 7 &=& (2 + 5) \\
  (1 + 7) &=& 8 &=& (3 + 5) \\
  (1 + 9) = (4 + 6) &=& 10 &=& (2 + 8) \\
  (1 + 10) = (4 + 7) &=& 11 &=& (3 + 8) \\
  (1 + 12) = (4 + 9) = (6 + 7) &=& 13 &=& (2 + 11) = (5 + 8) \\
  (4 + 10) &=& 14 &=& (3 + 11) \\
  (6 + 9) &=& 15 &=& (2 + 13) \\
  (1 + 15) = (4 + 12) = (6 + 10) = (7 + 9) &=& 16 &=& (2 + 14) = (3 + 13) = (5 + 11) \\
  (7 + 10) &=& 17 &=& (3 + 14) \\
  (6 + 12) &=& 18 &=& (5 + 13) \\
  (4 + 15) = (7 + 12) = (9 + 10) &=& 19 &=& (5 + 14) = (8 + 11) \\
  (6 + 15) = (9 + 12) &=& 21 &=& (8 + 13) \\
  (7 + 15) = (10 + 12) &=& 22 &=& (8 + 14) \\
  (9 + 15) &=& 24 &=& (11 + 13) \\
  (10 + 15) &=& 25 &=& (11 + 14) \\
  (12 + 15) &=& 27 &=& (13 + 14)
  \end{array}
- One possible partition for $n = 17$:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 17\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 15, 16\}.
  \end{align*}
- One possible partition for $n = 18$:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15, 18\}.
  \end{align*}
- Three possible partitions for $n = 20$:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 18, 19\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 17, 20\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 17, 20\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 20\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19\}.
  \end{align*}
- Two possible partitions for $n = 21$:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 18, 21\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 13, 14, 17, 19, 20\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 21\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 17, 19, 20\}.
  \end{align*}
- $7$ possible partitions for $n = 22$. Examples:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 22\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 22\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 19, 22\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 17, 18, 20, 23\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 19, 21, 22\}.
  \end{align*}
- $13$ possible partitions for $n = 23$. Examples:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 23\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 19, 21, 22\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 23\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 19, 21, 22\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 21, 22\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 23\}.
  \end{align*}
- $22$ possible partitions for $n = 24$. Examples:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 21, 24\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 24\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 17, 20, 22, 23\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 20, 22, 23\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21, 24\}.
  \end{align*}
- $38$ possible partitions for $n = 25$. Examples:
  \begin{align*}
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 22, 25\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 13, 17, 18, 21, 23, 24\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 25\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 15, 18, 21, 23, 24\}. \\ \\
  A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15, 18, 21, 23, 24\}, \\
  B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 25\}.
  \end{align*}
- $79$ possible partitions for $n = 26$.
- $145$ possible partitions for $n = 27$.
- $271$ possible partitions for $n = 28$.
- $484$ possible partitions for $n = 29$.
- $924$ possible partitions for $n = 30$.
- $1718$ possible partitions for $n = 31$.

For $n \in \{4, 8, 16\}$, the number of possible partitions is exactly one, but there are $3227$ possible partitions for $n = 32$. Examples:
\begin{align*}
A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 18, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 31\}, \\
B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 29, 32\}. \\ \\
A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 31\}, \\
B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 29, 32\}. \\ \\
A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 31\}, \\
B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 29, 32\}. \\ \\
A &= \{1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 29, 32\}, \\
B &= \{2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 13, 18, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 31\}.
\end{align*}

There are no partitions found when $n \in \{5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19\}$. I have not tested for $n > 32$.

Comment: Nothing to add to VTand's examples (TY!!). On a closely related problem, see _A gem of combinatorics_  in _In Polya's footsteps: Miscellaneous problems and essays_ by Ross Hornsberger (MAA,1979)